# Alter a 3 column layout currently using unordered lists and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, standards, frontend

I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve the layout shown here: http://cl.ly/image/0n0a293Z0O2m

Currently the code looks something like this.

```
<ul class="stats left">
  <li>168/299</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>56.2%</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>71</li>
</ul>

<ul class="stats right">
  <li>308/515</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>59.8%</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>80</li>
</ul>

<ul class="labels">
  <li>Completions/Attempts</li>
  <li>Touchdowns</li>
  <li>Completion %</li>
  <li>Interceptions</li>
  <li>Longest Pass</li>
</ul>
```

The way I choose to do it was to float each of the `stats` `UL's` left and then to absolutely position the `labels UL` to sit on top of the other two `UL's`

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3p4E/) of exactly how I am currently doing it.  I am just trying to get the easiest most practical way to achieve the same look, but do it without positioning absolutely and preferably without tables.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so please select it as your chosen answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SECOND EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/K3p4E/38/

CSS

```
#container {
    width:90%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.stats {
    background: #ececec;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
}
ul.stats > li, ul.labels > li {
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    line-height: 30px;
}
ul.labels > li {
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.labels {
    float:left;
    width: 34%;
}
#container h1 {
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    color:#0FF;
    line-height: 30px;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
     <h1>Passing</h1>
    <ul class="stats">
        <li>168/299</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>56.2%</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>71</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="labels">
        <li>Completions/Attempts</li>
        <li>Touchdowns</li>
        <li>Completion %</li>
        <li>Interceptions</li>
        <li>Longest Pass</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="stats">
        <li>308/515</li>
        <li>21</li>
        <li>59.8%</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>80</li>
    </ul>
     <h1>Rushing</h1>
    <ul class="stats">
        <li>168/299</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>56.2%</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>71</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="labels">
        <li>Completions/Attempts</li>
        <li>Touchdowns</li>
        <li>Completion %</li>
        <li>Interceptions</li>
        <li>Longest Pass</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="stats">
        <li>308/515</li>
        <li>21</li>
        <li>59.8%</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>80</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1ST EDIT

Change css to this:

```
ul.labels > li {
font-weight: bold;
width:300%;
}
ul.labels {
position:relative;
left:-30%;
float:left;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
}
```

Not sure if this is what you meant. The center stretches across all three ul's, however, this is very similar to your original posting, with a few advantages, specifically, a fluid layout. http://jsfiddle.net/K3p4E/29/

ORIGINAL POSTING:

fiddle with the widths and things and center the #content and this should do it for you.

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="stats">
    <li>168/299</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>56.2%</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>71</li>
</ul>
<ul class="labels">
    <li>Completions/Attempts</li>
    <li>Touchdowns</li>
    <li>Completion %</li>
    <li>Interceptions</li>
    <li>Longest Pass</li>
</ul>
<ul class="stats">
    <li>308/515</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>59.8%</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>80</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    width:90%;
}
ul.stats {
    background: #ececec;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}
ul.stats > li, ul.labels > li {
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    line-height: 30px;
}
ul.labels > li {
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.labels {
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Although you should reconsider a table. This kind of thing is what they were made for.

Comment: I'm new to jsfiddle but I figure this should be the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/K3p4E/13/

Comment: The only issue with this method is that I have headings that need to go all the way across. Between each of the UL's.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot again. What i'm referring to is the Passing Stats and the Rushing Stats that goes all the way across.

Comment: @jsheffers Sorry, I didn't notice those. See my second edit. Why do you want to avoid a table? They are not all bad.